Is there any way to change the position of the bar which shows the number of pages in Okular?
I have recently switched to the Okular application for PDF viewing again; it has improved significantly, at least from what I remember. Anyways, my question is: is it possible to change the position of the bar which shows the number of pages that the PDF has? The problem with this bar is that it occupies horizontal space in the bottom; if anything, I'd rather have it occupy the space below the other bars. In any case, this brings me to my next question, can it be set to also disappear when using fullscreen?
Thank you.

are you referring to the side panel? If so the left most icon on the top bar performs that function and the text element is displayed in the remaining space.
